# Is there any GPGPU library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gpgpu

Is there any [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) library for iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

The original iPhone and iPhone 3G support [only support OpenGL ES 1.1](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESontheiPhone/OpenGLESontheiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH101-SW1) fixed-function pipeline and do not provide a programmable pipeline (no shaders) and therefore cannot be used as general purpose computation devices, at least at the OpenGL abstraction layer.

iPhone 3GS and iPod touch 3G support OpenGL ES 2.0 programmable pipeline. However, it looks like there are limitations like lack of antialiased shaders.

Regardless of the support for programmable shaders in 3GS, I don't think the GPU is powerful enough to be used as a general purpose computational engine.

Comment: You can still do some basic GPGPU stuff even without shaders.  It's just extremely painful and limited in capability.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone GPU isn't built for general purpose computation, so hacking it for such features would be very limited and slow at best.

Pre 3GS' even have fixed pipeline chips, which makes computation on them impossible for almost all practical purposes.